# Given transition matrix of markov chain. Calculate $P(X_{12}=2, X_{16}=2 \mid X_0=0)$

Tags: probability, matrices, probability-theory, statistics, markov-chains

> $K= \begin{pmatrix}
> 0.3 & 0.3 & 0.4\\ 
> 0.2 & 0.7 & 0.1\\ 
> 0.2 & 0.3 & 0.5 \end{pmatrix}$  is the transition matrix of a markov chain, state space $S=\left\{0,1,2\right\}$.
>
> Calculate $P(X_{12}=2, X_{16}=2 \mid X_0=0)$

I have big problem solving this because I think you need program for it..? :(

But what I'm sure about is before you can calculate $P(X_{12}=2, X_{16}=2 \mid X_0 = 0)$, you need to calculate $P(X_{16}=2 \mid X_0=0)$ because I don't see direct way calculating it without knowing this first.

For $P(X_{16}=2 \mid X_0=0)$ I think I don't have a clear / good calculation because I wrote little program in java but it doesn't give precise results.. maybe they don't need to be as precise though. I have

$$P(X_{16}\mid X_0=0) = K^{16}_{0,2}$$ 
for $K^n$ we get approx this matrix when we start from $16$:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0.2222 & 0.5 & 0.2778\\ 
0.2222 & 0.5 & 0.2778\\ 
0.2222 & 0.5 & 0.2778
\end{pmatrix}$$

I have already trouble with this first calculation which we probably need to for the second but I can't even do it it is very brutal.. : /

Any way to do it more easy and precise?

Comment: You need $K^{12}$ and $K^4.$ Yes, that is a job for software. Can you write the desired conditional probability in terms of a 12-step transition followed by a 4-step transition? That would be a start towards the solution.

Comment: @BruceET Do you mean something like finding first $K^2$, then $(K^2)^2=K^4$ then $(K^4)^2=K^8$ then $(K^8)^2=K^{16}$? And also $K^{12} = K^8K^4$. But I have no idea how to write such software I didn't even have a class for doing it :( Maybe there is one online already for free you know about?

Comment: Your matrix for $K^{16}$ is actually correct to the number of digits you show. Nevertheless, as stated by others, you will never use $K^{16}$ to solve your problem.

Comment: Here's a free online matrix calculator (note: I haven't tried it, and can not vouch for its correctness) https://matrixcalc.org/en/. Or install software on your computer.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Does that mean my solution (the matrix) is correct for $P(X_{16}=2 | X_0=0)$?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't help you solve the problem you were given. Other comments and answers give you good hints what to do.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Alright thanks and thank you also for the link!! :)

Comment: It’s not *that* hard to diagonalize this matrix in order to compute powers of it. You know that one of the eigenvalues must be $1$, which makes finding the other two pretty simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
P(X_{16}=2, X_{12}=2|X_0=0) &= P(X_{16}=2|X_{12}=2, X_0=0) P (X_{12}=2|X_0=0) \\
&=P(X_{16}=2|X_{12}=2)P(X_{12}=2|X_0=0)\\
&=P(X_{4}=2|X_0=2)P(X_{12}=2|X_0=0)
\end{align}

Compute $P(X_{4}=2|X_0=2)$ and $P(X_{12}=2|X_0=0)$ and then multiply them.

Comment: I'm confronted with a similar question and maybe you can help me a little (I hope this is not against rules since it's not my question). If we are looking for $P(X_4=2 | X_0=2)$, then we need to do $K^4$ because we have $X_4$ and then the entry $p_{22}$ in matrix $K^4$ is what we were looking for, namely $P(X_4=2 | X_0 =2) = p_{22} \approx 0.51280$?

Comment: your description sounds ok.